# Setting REST Request Body

Tags: apex, rest-api, callout, httprequest, rest-service

I need to set below request body in a http rest callout which is working fine in postman.

```
[{
    "notification_type": "complaints",
    "notification_mode": "push", 
    "notification_title": "",
    "notification_message": "test notification with V0321E",
    "message_title": "",
    "message_body": "test message title with V0321E",
    "vendor_ids": [
        "V0321E"
    ],
    "meta_data": null,
    "tags": ""
}]
```

So basically I'm setting below request body in apex as below and it's not working[Basically it's getting 403 exception from the server which is returning 200 from postman. ].

```
map<string, object> reqBody = new map<string, object>{
            'notification_type' => 'complaints' ,
                'notification_mode' => 'push',
                'notification_title' => 'test' , 
                'notification_message' => 'test message' ,
                'message_title' => 'test' ,
                'message_body' => 'test body' ,
                'vendor_ids' => new List<String> {'V0321E'},  
                'tags' => ''
                };
```

Really appreciate any help on this.

Thanks,
Prasad

Comment: What does "It's not working" mean? Please [edit] your post to provide complete details of behavior and any errors verbatim. Since your Postman request body and your Apex don't even use the same set of fields, it's not clear that one result informs the other.

Comment: Sure @David, Basically it's getting 403 exception from the server which is returning 200 from postman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't make it a list:

```
list<object> reqBody = new List<Object> { 
  new map<string, object>{
    'notification_type' => 'complaints' ,
    'notification_mode' => 'push',
    'notification_title' => 'test' , 
    'notification_message' => 'test message' ,
    'message_title' => 'test' ,
    'message_body' => 'test body' ,
    'vendor_ids' => new List<String> {'V0321E'},  
    'tags' => ''
  }
};
```

Comment: thank you very much @sfdcfox, this is the exact thing I need.